# How to print JSON response in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am able to make a Ajax request and getting response as well in form of JSON string, still alert box of JavaScript is not showing actual response text.
I am new to ajax concept and dont know much.

Ajax-Call:-

```
Action triggered on dropdown
<select name="state" onchange="getOptions(this.value)">

Javascript Function called :-
function getOptions(state){
  AJAX.onreadystatechange = handler;
  AJAX.open("GET", "getData?id="+state);
  AJAX.send();
};
```

Response Firebug is showing

[image: Response Content]

This is my code to fetch response and print.

```
function handler() {
  if(AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
    var json = eval('(' + AJAX.responseText +')');
    alert('Success. Result:' + json);
  }
  else if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status != 200) {
      alert('Something went wrong...');
  }
}
```

Every time its a success but i get output as 
[image]

Comment: do `var res=JSON.parse(AJAX.responseText); alert(res.name)`...It will alert `Dehradun`

Comment: i tried that also , still same result

Comment: It is an array. You need res[0]. But why not use jQuery if you tag the question jQuery?

Comment: Do something like `res[0].name`.. where `res[0]` is the first object in array got after `JSON.parse(AJAX.responseText)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to treat your response as JSON not as text.

Try this:

```
function handler() {
    if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(AJAX.responseText), len = json.length, i = 0, txt = "";
        for (; i < len; i++) {
            if (txt) {
                txt += ", ";
            }
            txt += json[i].name;
        }
        alert('Success. Result:' + txt);
    } else if (AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status != 200) {
        alert('Something went wrong...');
    }
}
```

Comment: How about the more efficient `for (; i < len; i++) {
                txt += ", "+json[i].name;
        } if (txt) txt = txt.substring(2);`  -also use console instead of alert in async processing

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see the value as part of debugging the code, you should use
 `console.log(AJAX)` to inspect the value.

If you really need to display some message to the user, then reconsider showing the json result unformatted/filtered - that said you *could* iterate through all the objects properties and concenate theese in a string (like @Hiral shows).